# Git push origin master having publickey issues

Tags: git, github, ubuntu-11.10

I'm having some trouble committing a default rails app to git, and I've hit a wall in troubleshooting the problem. I am currently running Ubuntu 11.10. I am running git version 1.7.5.4. I ran through the series of

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin git@github.com:username/first_app.git
git push -u origin master
```

I also make the repo on github.com, but then I get this error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the public key of your system to the git admin interface on github.com.

https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys